# How to use pre-installed applications on a fresh operating system?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, windows-10

I performed a reset on my computer and installed Windows 10. To save space on my SSD (C:), I installed the majority of my applications in another drive (A:\Program Files). Obviously after the reset the program files are still there.

My question is that do I have to download all of my applications again or is there a way I can use these program files on my new system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you performed a Reset, you uninstalled all your applications, part of the description of that function indicates you will have to reinstalled your applications.

Answer (score 1):

Some applications may run when executed from your `A:` drive manually. However, most applications are so much more than just a collection of executable files. There are registry entries, hooks, temporary files, user specific files and settings and more! Also, the applications you installed, were installed for Windows 7. The Windows 10 installer hasn't checked these applications for compatibility issues.

Sure, you could try and run them by looking up their master `.exe` files. However, if you want them to run properly, just reinstall them. You can then manually copy files from `A:` that you really want back, like settings.

Comment: Yeah, they work when I go directly to the application directory. I was just hoping there could be a way to install them with just the files. I guess not. :/

Comment: @kkmonlee not automagically anyway! You could take your chances and simple create shortcuts to the .exe files. This isn't the same as properly installing them, though.